# Why am I getting multiple headings in a query to a single table

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am trying to diagnose problems with a larger query, so I started from the basics. I noticed that when I query one table I am getting 12 rows selected but the last row has it's own header, which is the same header of the result set. Why would this be?

```
 SELECT  *
 FROM testtable;
```

Results

```
 testid   personid   role
 __________________________
   1          1       memeber
   2          3       memeber
   3          1       chair
   etc etc    etc
```

then at the last row I get another header

```
  testid    personid   role
 ____________________________
   4           2      member
```

This may be a dumb question but I couldn't find an answer searching and I am new and learning SQL.

Comment: No idea what you mean? Are you talking about console output?

Comment: The output from sql plus console query has multiple header rows ... Every other table only would have one header row

Comment: As shown above their are two header or heading rows of testid, personid and role..... Just wondering why this is... Is this how output is formatted after so many rows or do I have corrupt data somewhere? I don't get this with any other query so I don't know how normal this is.

Comment: you need set the line size and page size  if you are using sqlplus

Comment: That might be it... how can I see what their currently set at?

Comment: For line size `show linesize` for Page size `show pagesize`